# В какой момент переходить с Java на Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Уже достаточное время я занимаюсь изучением языка Java. И в ближайшие дни собираюсь учить Java core. В целях заняться разработкой под андроид. После каких изученных технологий java лучше переходить на Kotlin?

Comment: `Java` и `Kotlin` это два разных языка.  Вы можете и не переходить с одного на другой, если вам нравится разрабатывать на `Java`. И наоборот: если вам понравится разрабатывать на `Kotlin`, то у Вас особо нет причин НЕ переходить на него прямо сейчас. Но для этого Вам нужно попробовать и потыкать котлин немного. Ну и с другой стороны Вас тоже могут не спрашивать...к примеру работодатель или рынок... Если они потребуют, то скорее всего Вам придётся подчиниться, несмотря на свои предпочтения. При разработке на Андроиде лучше иметь в своём арсенале оба. И никто вам не мешает изучать их параллельно

Comment: В общем Вам нужно самому пробовать и самому решать... за вас никто этот выбор не сделает. Но изучать котлин прямо сейчас вам никто не мешает. Единственное что можно сказать точно: если перед вами стал такой вопрос, то просто изучите хотя бы поверхностно котлин прямо сейчас... а там вам уже виднее будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать тот язык, который вы знаете, который вам нравится и который вам подходит под ваши задачи. На выбор языка влияют разные факторы. В вашем случае:

- *Если* нравится и то и то, *то* используйте и то и то: [java](/questions/tagged/java) и [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin).
- *Если* у вас есть необходимость, *то* используйте тот, который нужен.
- Язык не бывает "лишним" — он в любом (может) случае пригодится.

Вывод: it's up to you. Good luck anyway! ;)